# Inner Join with Group_Concat

Tags: mysql, join, group-concat

I am somewhat new to joins so pardon if this question seems self-evident.

I am doing a group_concat to create a delimited field from Table1 e.g.

```
Select FieldA,FieldB,group_concat(FieldC) from Table1 group by FieldA,FieldB
```

However the group_concat can get quite large and I only want those FieldC records where they exist in another table, Table2 already.

I understand I can do a basic join as

```
SELECT FieldC FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.FieldC = Table2.FieldC
```

However I am not sure how to construct that so that the Select/Join from Table1 is returned as a group_concat not a list.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing like a little sweat equity

```
SELECT FieldA,FIeldB,Group_Concat(FieldC) FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.FieldC = Table2.FieldC group by FieldA,FieldB
```